# How to hide overflow when sliding an element of an SVG in using keyframe animation?

Tags: css, animation, svg

I need to slide up the entire hand and phone element (hand_phone class) onto it's current position on the red background. The trouble I have is only showing the hand when it's on the red background, not sliding it up on the blue or white. As if the hand and phone is behind everything else and the red box is a window. I've tried clipPath, hidden: overflow, but not having any luck.

https://jsfiddle.net/8moofbef/3/

```
.hand_phone {
  animation: slide 1s;
}

@keyframes slide {
from {transform: translateY(400px)}
to {transform: translateY(0px)}
}
```

Comment: i don't get what's your doubt.

Answer (score 0):

1. Define the `<clipPath>` that you want the hand to appear inside of. In this case it's just a `<rect>` the same size as the red one.

   ```
   <defs>
     <clipPath id="red-rect-clip">
       <rect x="167.5" y="981.4" class="st2" width="391.7" height="451"/>
     </clipPath>  
   </defs>
   ```
2. Secondly, you need apply the clip path to the correct elements.  It can't be `<g class="hand_phone">` because that is being animated with a transform. And any transform you apply to that will also move the clip path that is attached to it.

   So what you need to do is surround the "hand_phone" elements with a parent group.  Then apply the clip path to that.  That way the clip doesn't move, and you get the effect you want.

   ```
   <g clip-path="url(#red-rect-clip)">
     <g class="hand_phone">
       <...>
     </g>
   </g>
   ```

```css
.hand_phone {
  animation: slide 1s;
}

@keyframes slide {
from {transform: translateY(400px)}
to {transform: translateY(0px)}
}
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
  viewBox="0 0 1920 1920" style="enable-background:new 0 0 1920 1920;" xml:space="preserve">

<defs>
  <clipPath id="red-rect-clip">
    <rect x="167.5" y="981.4" class="st2" width="391.7" height="451"/>
  </clipPath>  
</defs>

<style type="text/css">
 .st0{fill:#057BDB;}
 .st1{fill:#FFFFFF;}
 .st2{fill:#FF0049;}
 .st3{clip-path:url(#SVGID_2_);}
 .st4{fill:#01434C;}
 .st5{fill:#03828E;}
 .st6{fill:#085E67;}
 .st7{fill:#6CB5AE;}
 .st8{fill:#25A599;}
 .st9{fill:#B5B5B5;}
 .st10{fill:#DDDDDD;}
 .st11{fill:#F27040;}
 .st12{fill:#F48359;}
 .st13{fill:#F05A2B;}
 .st14{fill:#253D46;}
 .st15{fill:#969BA4;}
 .st16{fill:#465B66;}
 .st17{fill:#AFBDC5;}
 .st18{fill:#FF8B00;}
 .st19{fill:#566D78;}
 .st20{fill:#5D6972;}
 .st21{fill:#78909B;}
 .st22{fill:#F8A773;}
 .st23{fill:#FAB685;}
 .st24{fill:#F79B6A;}
 .st25{fill:#140F2C;}
 .st26{fill:#E5E5E5;}
 .st27{fill:#F4F4F4;}
 .st28{fill:#150E39;}
 .st29{fill:#1C1749;}
 .st30{fill:#171043;}
 .st31{fill:#5E6A7E;}
 .st32{fill:#0A038E;}
 .st33{fill:#30120B;}
 .st34{fill:#CBE6F3;}
 .st35{fill:#838E93;}
 .st36{fill:#BCB1D7;}
 .st37{fill:#9F98C6;}
 .st38{fill:#D8CEE6;}
 .st39{fill:#FF88A7;}
 .st40{fill:#EAEBF0;}
 .st41{fill:#F0F1F8;}
 .st42{fill:#D5DAEE;}
 .st43{fill:#378E43;}
 .st44{fill:#BD3A27;}
 .st45{fill:#795549;}
 .st46{fill:#F69D5E;}
 .st47{fill:#221F1F;}
 .st48{fill:#403F41;}
 .st49{fill:#E6E6E7;}
 .st50{fill-rule:evenodd;clip-rule:evenodd;fill:#D0A785;}
 .st51{fill-rule:evenodd;clip-rule:evenodd;fill:#FFD6B6;}
 .st52{fill-rule:evenodd;clip-rule:evenodd;fill:#AAAAAA;}
 .st53{fill-rule:evenodd;clip-rule:evenodd;fill:#CCE9F9;}
 .st54{fill-rule:evenodd;clip-rule:evenodd;fill:#FFFFFF;}
 .st55{fill-rule:evenodd;clip-rule:evenodd;fill:#CBCBCB;}
 .st56{fill-rule:evenodd;clip-rule:evenodd;fill:#989898;}
 .st57{fill-rule:evenodd;clip-rule:evenodd;fill:#93C6E2;}
 .st58{fill:#CBCBCB;}
 .st59{fill:#E6E6E6;}
 .st60{fill:#96BEE5;}
 .st61{opacity:0.5;fill:#F2F2F2;}
 .st62{fill:#F2F2F2;}
 .st63{fill:#CBCDCE;}
 .st64{fill:#0D3EB7;}
 .st65{fill:#4D4D4D;}
 .st66{opacity:0.1;}
 .st67{fill:#808080;}
 .st68{fill:#D7D8D9;}
 .st69{fill:#F1F2F2;}
 .st70{fill:#FFFEF7;}
 .st71{fill:#BDCAE8;}
 .st72{opacity:0.5;fill:#FFFFFF;}
 .st73{fill:#D7D7D7;}
 .st74{fill:#D7869D;}
 .st75{opacity:0.2;fill-rule:evenodd;clip-rule:evenodd;fill:#1A1A1A;}
 .st76{opacity:0.65;}
 .st77{fill:none;stroke:#ED1C24;stroke-width:2;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
 .st78{fill:none;stroke:#ED1C24;stroke-width:2;stroke-miterlimit:10;stroke-dasharray:1.9968,1.9968;}
 .st79{opacity:0.95;fill:none;stroke:#ED1C24;stroke-width:2;stroke-miterlimit:10;stroke-dasharray:2;}
 .st80{fill:#567396;}
 .st81{fill:#FFFFFF;stroke:#057BDB;stroke-width:0.75;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
</style>

<g>
 <rect y="-1" class="st0" width="1920" height="1920"/>
  
  <g class="white_rectangle">
   <rect x="140.6" y="666.1" class="st1" width="849.2" height="793.9"/>
  </g>
  
 <g class="red_rectangle">
   <rect x="167.5" y="981.4" class="st2" width="391.7" height="451"/>
 </g>

  <g clip-path="url(#red-rect-clip)">
    <g class="hand_phone">
    <path class="st46" d="M435.6,1066.8l-16,21c-4.1,5.3-23.5,14.4-  15.2,22.4c10.1,9.7,22.5,10.1,26.5,5.8l28-31
    c4.2-5.1,10.1-14.8,1.3-23.2C450.1,1052,439.5,1062.5,435.6,1066.8z"/>
    <path class="st46" d="M280.3,1138.7c-0.6,33.7-3.4,107.9-3.4,107.9s-1.2,15.3,4.8,22.2c6.1,6.9,15.1,9.9,15.1,9.9l-15.1,31.5
    l80.3,42.6l56.4-87.9l-118.3-110.6C300.2,1154.2,303.5,1137,280.3,1138.7z"/>
    <path class="st47" d="M418.3,1044.1H312.8c-7.1,0-12.9,5.8-12.9,12.9v201.7c0,7.2,5.8,12.9,12.9,12.9h105.5
     c7.2,0,12.9-5.8,12.9-12.9v-201.7C431.3,1049.9,425.5,1044.1,418.3,1044.1z"/>
    <rect x="308" y="1072.8" class="st1" width="115.2" height="167.1"/>
    <circle class="st48" cx="365.6" cy="1060" r="4.8"/>
    <path class="st48" d="M374,1250.7h-16.8c-2.9,0-5.3,2.4-5.3,5.3c0,2.9,2.4,5.3,5.3,5.3H374c2.9,0,5.3-2.4,5.3-5.3
     C379.3,1253,376.9,1250.7,374,1250.7z"/>

     <path class="st46" d="M424.7,1208l-5.1,6.5c-4.1,5.3-9,14.4-0.7,22.4c10.1,9.7,20.7-0.8,24.6-5.1l4.4-5.6
    c4.2-5.1,10.1-14.8,1.3-23.2C439.2,1193.3,428.6,1203.8,424.7,1208z"/>
     <path class="st46" d="M424.7,1166.5l-5.1,6.5c-4.1,5.3-9,14.4-0.7,22.4c10.1,9.7,20.7-0.8,24.6-5.1l4.4-5.6
    c4.2-5.1,10.1-14.8,1.3-23.2C439.2,1151.8,428.6,1162.2,424.7,1166.5z"/>
     <path class="st46" d="M424.7,1124.6l-5.1,6.4c-4.1,5.3-9,14.4-0.7,22.4c10.1,9.7,20.7-0.8,24.6-5l4.4-5.6
    c4.2-5.1,10.1-14.8,1.3-23.2C439.2,1109.9,428.6,1120.4,424.7,1124.6z"/>
     <polygon class="st49" points="270.7,1297.2 200,1433.1 335.4,1433.1 376.7,1353.7    "/>
      <polygon class="st1" points="270.7,1297.2 200,1433.1 267.7,1433.1 323.7,1325.5    "/>
    </g>
  </g>
</g>
</svg>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/8moofbef/4/